# How to send a fake geocode to geocoder.getCurrentPosition() with selenium or cucumber?

Tags: html, selenium, cucumber, geocoding

I develop my application trough cucumber behaviours and I want to include the [HTML5 getCurrentPosition](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html).

Is there a way to send such a geolocation from either the Firefox-browser in Selenium or from the Capybara-browser in Cucumber?

My application now calls `navigator.geocoder.getCurrentPosition(some_callback)` to request the location from the user. Modern browsers and most mobile browsers will prompt the user whether they want to send their location to the application. 
I want to fake this behaviour and simply send a lat:long to my application when testing.

Comment: Do you need to call getCurrentPosition or do you just need a long and lat? Because if you just need those two you can create them yourself instead of calling the function.

Comment: Or else you could start FireFox with an addon that can fake your location

Comment: I've clarified a bit in an edit to the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my Cucumber Features do not test whether or not the Google Maps JavaScript actually works, I decided to simply add a small test-extension to that JavaScript.

The JavaScript now simply picks up the parameters `latitude=8&longitude=52` and uses that, to mock `getCurrentPosition` when given. An additional parameter `test` can be used to render a string representing the "center" of the map, which is testable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ((urlParam('latitude') >= 0) && (urlParam('longitude') >= 0)) {
    var latitude = urlParam('latitude')
    var longitude = urlParam('longitude')
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) {
      var position = {"coords" : { "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude }};

      if (urlParam('test') >= 0) { #extension for testability
        $("#map_canvas").html("latitude: "+ latitude +" longitude: "+ longitude);
      }

      success(position);
    }
  }
});
```

Where `urlParam()` is a helper function to determine params in the URL: returning `null` if not found.

The added benefit, is that maps are "linkable", you can now craft a URL and use that to center the map.

My step defenition is:

```
Then /^it should center the map on my current location$/ do
  visit maps_path({:latitude => 20, :longitude => 20, :test => true})
  page.should have_content "latitude: 20 longitude: 20"
end
```